# Pass timestamp system property from Gradle to Android (Java) application

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I want my Android application to know at runtime when the application was built. I am new to Gradle, but it seems very flexible and I think it might be possible to achieve this without any external helper programs or token replacement.

My idea was to compute a timestamp string in some sort of a Gradle pre-build task. Then I would like to pass this string as a system property to the Java application. For example:

```
def timestamp = ...
systemProperty 'my.build.timestamp' timestamp
```

And then retrieve the timestamp at runtime in Java:

```
String iWasBuiltAt = System.getProperty("my.build.timestamp");
```

How would I go about writing the neccesary Gradle code to achieve this? More specifically, where/how do invoke my custom task and is it possible to add system properties in such a way as described above.

Comment: are you using this for version number?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to programmatically read the date when my Android apk was built?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3540739/how-to-programmatically-read-the-date-when-my-android-apk-was-built)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following will add a `buildTime` constant to your BuildConfig class (this class is auto-generated by the build system).

```
defaultConfig {
    buildConfig  "public final static String buildTime = \"" + new Date() + "\";"
}
```

In any Android Java file, you can use it like so (The build config is in the default package of your app which you will have to import):

```
Log.v("foo", "buildtime:" + BuildConfig.buildTime);
```

You can use groovy date formatting functions to format the date differently. You could also change this to store the epoch milliseconds and then parse it in Java.

`defaultConfig` means that this will be added builds of every `buildType`.

Read more about build types, the `defaultConfig` etc. here : http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide

Not sure why you would want to know this in the app. I think using the revision number or hash of your version control system might make more sense than the date.

Comment: Great! I use the build time to determine the expiration date of an internal "evaluation" flavor of my app.

Comment: `buildConfigField "long", "BUILD_TIME_MILLIS", "${System.currentTimeMillis()}L"`