# Fixing the "Build Type contains custom BuildConfig fields, but the feature is disabled" error w/ buildConfigField

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, android-buildconfig

In the new version of Android Studio (Flamingo | 2022.2.1 Canary 9) with the org.jetbrains.kotlin (1.8.0-Beta) plugin and 8.0.0-alpha09 gradle plugin, a new build suddenly gets this error:

> Build Type 'release' contains custom BuildConfig fields, but the feature is disabled.

Is there a way to make this go away?

Answer (score 145):

Answering my own question -- there *is* a quick solution.  Try adding the following line to `gradle.properties`, and the problem should hopefully stop bothering you (for now):

```
android.defaults.buildfeatures.buildconfig=true
```

Or, per @Scott_AGP's answer, it may be better to add this to `build.gradle` instead of changing `gradle.properties`:

```
android {
    buildFeatures {
        buildConfig = true
    }
}
```

This issue is due to the deprecation of `buildConfigField` (from android.packageBuildConfig) as described [in this commit](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/+/370c706fb6553dc5952e10323a81f2b195405c3f%5E%21/).

**UPDATE 12/12/22:**

Per a note from [Roar Grønmo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4475206/roar-gr%C3%B8nmo) below, there is a newer way to sneak the timestamp into the `BuildConfig.java` file [than the one I suggested back in 2014.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3540739/how-to-programmatically-read-the-date-when-my-android-apk-was-built/22649533#22649533)

To use this newer method, first delete any lines in your current `build.gradle` (or `build.gradle.kts`) file that looks like:

```
buildConfigField("String", "BUILD_TIME", "\"" + System.currentTimeMillis().toString() + "\"")
```

Instead, first add the following to the top of your `build.gradle.kts`:

```
import com.android.build.api.variant.BuildConfigField
```

and outside of the `android { ... }` part of `build.config.kts` add this:

```
androidComponents {
    onVariants {
       it.buildConfigFields.put(
            "BUILD_TIME", BuildConfigField(
                "String", "\"" + System.currentTimeMillis().toString() + "\"", "build timestamp"
            )
        )
    }
}
```

You shouldn't have to make any new changes to your main codebase-- the timestamp can still be accessed in Kotlin like this:

```
private val buildDate = Date(BuildConfig.BUILD_TIME.toLong())
Log.i("MyProgram", "This .apk was built on ${buildDate.toString()}");
```

That's it!  Note this still requires the change to `gradle.properties` described above or you will see an **Accessing value buildConfigFields in variant ____ has no effect as the feature buildConfig is disabled.** warning.

There may still be a better way to do this without using `BuildConfigField`, but if so, I don't know it.  If anyone has a more permanent fix, please let me (us) know.

Comment: I found a similar problem for an older v of AS here https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/161727311, but that one introduces another way if setting those values through gradle. Haven't testet them yet.

Comment: Confirming that setting `android.defaults.buildfeatures.buildconfig=true` doesn't produce error when building project, but hasn't check other influences yet.

Comment: buildConfig = true fixed my isssue

Comment: I want to add it to `buildTypes` instead of `onVariants` and I can still use it:  `buildTypes { getByName("debug") { buildConfigField(`....`)....

Comment: Android studio it self suggests to set  `android.buildFeatures.buildConfig true` in app `build.gradle`, so I added  

`android {
    buildFeatures {
        buildConfig = true
    }
} `   and it worked for me too.

Answer (score 100):

Avoid adding `android.defaults.buildfeatures.buildconfig=true` to your `gradle.properties` file because that property is [deprecated in AGP 8.0 and is scheduled to be removed in AGP 9.0](https://cs.android.com/android-studio/platform/tools/base/+/0bc1c23297760643b03e8cfd8acc52c007a99cd6).

Instead, add the following to the per-module `build.gradle` file for each module using `BuildConfig`:

```
android {
    buildFeatures {
        buildConfig = true
    }
}
```

Comment: for each module? What is this 1995?

Comment: @Dazzle "Always has been" meme

Answer (score 7):

add these lines to your gradle.properties:

```
android.buildConfig=true
API_KEY=0000
```

and these to build.gradle(module):

```
buildFeatures {
        buildConfig = true
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

I'll just add this alternative "solution" here... For whomever it might help ?

From [developer.android.com documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/tools/gradle-api/7.4/com/android/build/api/dsl/BuildFeatures#buildConfig()) :

> You can override the default for this for all projects in your build
> by adding the line `android.defaults.buildfeatures.buildconfig=true` in
> the `gradle.properties` file at the root project of your build.

So one might just want to explicitly declare that in his project level `gradle.properties`.

Answer (score 3):

adding `android.defaults.buildfeatures.buildconfig=true` to your `gradle.properties` would fix this.

Comment: Humbly downvoted this, since solution is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Or apply it via android/build.gradle

```
allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
}
//ERROR Caused by: org.gradle.api.reflect.ObjectInstantiationException:
// Could not create an instance of type com.android.build.api.variant.impl.LibraryVariantBuilderImpl.
subprojects {
    afterEvaluate { project ->
        if (project.hasProperty('android')) {
            project.android {
                if (namespace == null) {
                    namespace project.group
                }
                // Avoid adding android.defaults.buildfeatures.buildconfig=true
                // to your gradle.properties file because that property is deprecated in AGP 8.0 and is scheduled to be removed in AGP 9.0.
                buildFeatures {
                    if (buildConfig == null) {
                        buildConfig true
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```