# How to resolve AGP build error Product Flavor 'development' contains custom BuildConfig fields, but the feature is disabled

Tags: android-gradle-plugin

I just upgraded my android studio to ...

```
Android Studio Flamingo | 2022.2.1 Canary 9
Build #AI-222.4345.14.2221.9321504, built on November 22, 2022
Runtime version: 17.0.4.1+0-17.0.4.1b469.62-9127311 x86_64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
macOS 10.15.7
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 4096M
Cores: 12
Metal Rendering is ON
Registry:
    external.system.auto.import.disabled=true
    ide.text.editor.with.preview.show.floating.toolbar=false
    ide.images.show.chessboard=true
    gradle.version.catalogs.dynamic.support=trueNon-Bundled Plugins:
    com.android.aas (3.5.1)
    com.jetbrains.kmm (0.5.1(222)-30)
```

then I upgraded AGP to...

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '8.0.0-alpha09' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '8.0.0-alpha09' apply false
}
```

now my gradle sync task reports these warnings...

```
    Product Flavor 'staging' contains custom BuildConfig fields, but the feature is disabled.
    Affected Modules: network, resource, access
```

and now my build fails with this...

```
    FAILURE: 
Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
    A problem occurred configuring project ':background:network'.
    com.android.builder.errors.EvalIssueException: Product Flavor 'development' contains custom BuildConfig fields, but the feature is disabled.
```

Comment: see for fix https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74634321/fixing-the-new-build-type-contains-custom-buildconfig-fields-but-the-feature