# Is there a new way to set 'buildConfigField' values in Gradle 9.0?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

Our app has a large number of gradle command line options that affect runtime behavior in Kotlin. I use 'buildConfigField' values to pass parameters from command line into Kotlin in order to implement these variations.

The 'buildConfigField' parameter is going away in grade 9.0 but is there another way to pass gradle command line parameters into Kotlin code?

Comment: "The 'buildConfigField' parameter is going away in Android Gradle Plugin 9.0" - Where are you inferring this information from?

Comment: That's what it says in the Build window.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74692390/13021452), you should add the following code to each one of the module that utilizes the BuildConfig file:

```
android {
    buildFeatures {
        buildConfig = true
    }
}
```

The person that asked the question initially also has a few alternatives to your potential issue, as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74634322/13021452), but I'm not sure if he's recommendations will persist once Gradle 9 is upon us.